# Quit LLDB with exit code of process

Tags: lldb

After my process has finished, I want to quit LLDB with the same exit code as the process. In GDB I would do

```
(gdb) quit $_exitcode
```

Is there an equivalent for LLDB?

Answer (score 2):

The ability to supply the exitcode to the "quit" command was added to lldb fairly recently.  lldb doesn't use have the equivalent of $_exitcode state variables.  Since one debug session can be debugging multiple processes, there isn't a global exitcode anyway.

So if you want to run a process, capture its return value and quit with that value, you will have to write a Python command.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Python wrapper script which will run the command given under lldb, print a backtrace on crash, and exit with the command's exit code:

```py
import sys
import os
import subprocess

sys.path.append(subprocess.getoutput('lldb -P'))
import lldb

exe = sys.argv[1]
args = sys.argv[2:]

debugger = lldb.SBDebugger.Create()
# Block until target process exits.
debugger.SetAsync(False)
target = debugger.CreateTargetWithFileAndArch(exe, lldb.LLDB_ARCH_DEFAULT)
if not target:
    print('failed to create target')
    exit(1)

process = target.LaunchSimple(args, None, os.getcwd())
if process.exit_state < 0:
    for thread in process.threads:
        print(thread)
        for frame in thread.frames:
            print('   ', frame)
        print()
sys.exit(process.exit_state)
```